# How to change anchor point?

Tags: ios, objective-c, scenekit, anchorpoint, scnnode

I'm working with `SceneKit`. The object `SCNNode` is rotated relative to the center. How to change anchor point of the `SCNNode`?

```
SCNScene *scene = [SCNScene new];

SCNBox *boxGeometry = [SCNBox boxWithWidth:384.f height:512.f length:20.f chamferRadius:0];

SCNMaterial *material = [SCNMaterial new];
material.diffuse.contents = [UIImage imageNamed:@"material"];

SCNNode *boxNode = [SCNNode nodeWithGeometry:boxGeometry];
boxNode.geometry.firstMaterial = material;
boxNode.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
[scene.rootNode addChildNode:boxNode];

self.sceneView.scene = scene;
self.sceneView.allowsCameraControl = YES;
```

Answer (score 3):

Your pivot transform translation is very small compared to the size of your box. It's not normalized.

If you want to translate around one of the corners you should translate half of the side in all directions.

```
boxNode.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(384.0/2.0, 512.0/2.0, 20.0/2.0);
```

Comment: how do you rotate your object? If you are relying on `allowsCameraControl` it's the wrong approach. You need to manipulate nodes yourself (either a camera or the box).

Answer (score 0):

As a simple example :

yourSceneNode.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0.5, 0.5, 0.5),

where you change the node's position, rotation and scale properties.

SCNNode class reference explains this nicely

Comment: Thank you for answer, but it doesn't work. Look at my code above.

Comment: hmm.. what's the problem you are having now.Some kind of error ??

Comment: No, my object is rotating around the center. I need rotate an object around left side like opening a book.